GPG verification enabled, but no signatures found
I am Ubuntu 22.04 LTS user.
I am getting this error when trying to install "Varia download manager":

[error: error pulling from repo:
gpg verification enabled, but no signatures found
(use gpg-verify=false in remote config to disable)]

I already installed Flatpak.
How can I solve this problem?
